# Redux and Angular 2

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, angular, redux

Is it approved to use `Redux` with `Angular 2` for state management, or does Angular 2 provide some internal mechanism to manage the application state in a consistent way?

Answer (score 8):

"Internally" it is not a bundled feature or module. But the guys @NGRX have done an absolutely fantastic job in supporting this pattern in angular2.

Take a look at these following resources for more details:
https://github.com/ngrx/store

https://blog.sstorie.com/building-an-angular-2-reactive-auto-logout-timer-with-the-redux-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 does not come with its own state management pattern nor does it enforces one in particular that being said its architecture follows React's approach very closely and as far as I know you have two ways to implement a Flux approach to your NG2 App, [NgRx](https://github.com/ngrx) and [Angular Redux](https://github.com/angular-redux).

Personally I have not used Angular Redux, as NgRx seems to be the most used and recommended solution, it is also quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 come with RxJS in bundle

here some interesting url

http://blog.angular-university.io/functional-reactive-programming-for-angular-2-developers-rxjs-and-observables/

https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way we working in Angular 2 is little bit different from React, because in Angular we use services and components. I think that the principle of Redux is great but you need to apply it in a different way in Angular.

I wrote an article that offers a solution for that
[Angular 2 state store strategy (using RXBox)](https://medium.com/@ariel.henryson/angular-2-state-store-strategy-using-rxbox-62eaf3251e90#.da2r39h43)

Answer (score 0):

We can use Angular with Redux, but the structure of Angular is different, it's better using services rather than using Redux with that...

But if you still like to use Redux with Angular, have a look at ng-redux, you can check it out here:

https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux

Also this is a good blog post about Angular Redux:

http://blog.rangle.io/managing-state-redux-angular